# ReferenceError: $ is not defined strange

Tags: jquery

How come everything in homecooked.js works but the script that is below it does not and the browser gives me "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" on that specific part?

```
    <script src="assets/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/homecooked.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        <?php if($profile_messages){?>
            $('.page').hide().eq('2').show();
        <?php } else { ?>
            $('.page:gt(0)').hide();
        <?php } 

        for($i = 0; $i < ($image_array_length); $i++){ ?>
                $(".modal-textarea").limit("120",".comment-counter");
            <?php }?>
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Is the error being thrown on the `$(document).ready` binding line?  Is `jQuery` defined if `$` is not?

Comment: You're probably redefining `$` somewhere, try using `jQuery` instead of the dollarsign and see if that works. Assuming homecooked.js uses jQuery, and not just native JS.

Comment: Can you inspect the page and see if the script is really loaded? Maybe your path is wrong..

Comment: the script is loaded since all the functions in homecooked works fine. I'm going to try with jQuery instead of dollar

Comment: rather than changing all of the code you could also wrap that entire piece in the standard `(function($) { /*existing code here*/ }(jQuery));`

Comment: okay I managed to fix it thanks to you guys. It was that I already used it somewhere in the php file that I did not need.

Answer (score 1):

try changing with this one:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

we can use the dollar sign in place of jQuery as much as we like this way.

you can take a look at the documentations here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring